# Prevent color in code sample formatting / highlighting

Tags: discussion

How can we make a code sample *without* any color being applied to that code?

#### Example

A classic use case would be console output, which often looks clearer inside code sample formatting, but isn't itself code. Note: I realise that's subjective, so for precision, please assume this question only applies where the author *intends* to place something which isn't strictly code inside code sample formatting (i.e. that they haven't done so in error)

Random example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56301481/5783745); it's arguably easier to read in code sample formatting (even though it's strictly not code, but console output), but would be ideal to limit the color to black only (i.e. no blue)

[image]

<sub>I'm *sure* this would have been asked before, but I can't spot it via searches.</sub>

Comment: Add the `none` language tag

Comment: @CertainPerformance brilliant! thanks. should I delete this question?

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry to have asked it, I knew it would be somewhere

Comment: Hint for searching: Stack Exchange search isn’t very good, so use Google and search like this: `site:meta.stackoverflow.com disable syntax-highlighting`.

Comment: @user4642212 thanks I will remember to search that way. Regarding the related question, I hadn't encountered this sort of structure before `<!-- language: lang-<language> -->` It looks like HTML commenting, with some key/value inside.

Comment: @stevec I wouldn't delete this. Duplicate questions aren't inherently bad. They provide signposts, so other people have an easier time finding the answers.

Comment: @stevec If you're using code fences there's an even easier shorthand - just add the language tag at the end of the opening fence, e.g. `\`\`\`java` or `\`\`\`none`